# How to convert std::chrono::time_point to string

Tags: c++11, c++-chrono

How to convert `std::chrono::time_point` to string? 
For example: `"201601161125"`.

Comment: Have you tried inserting it in `std::stringstream` and then converting it to string using stringstream's member function `.str()`?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'll do that. If your tip works, I'll let you know.

Comment: See:  http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html  Section "What about a date-time type?"

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Update for C++20:

This can now easily be done in C++20:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::chrono::time_point tp = std::chrono::sys_days{2016y/1/16} + 11h + 25min;
    std::string s = std::format("{:%Y%m%d%H%M}", tp);
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
201601161125
```

[Demo.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qoa39865n)

### Original Answer:

[Howard Hinnant's free, open source, header-only, portable date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) is a modern way to do this that doesn't traffic through the old C API, and doesn't require that you discard all of your sub-second information.  This library is also being [proposed for standardization](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0355r3.html).

There is a lot of flexibility in formatting.  The easiest way is to just stream out:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now() << '\n';
}
```

This just output for me:

```
2017-09-15 13:11:34.356648
```

The `using namespace date;` is required in order to find the streaming operator for the `system_clock::time_point` (it isn't legal for my lib to insert it into `namespace std::chrono`).  No information is lost in this format:  the full precision of your `system_clock::time_point` will be output (`microseconds` where I ran this on macOS).

The full suite of [`strftime`-like formatting flags](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html#to_stream_formatting) is available for other formats, with minor extensions to handle things like fractional seconds.  Here is another example that outputs with millisecond precision:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::cout << format("%D %T %Z\n", floor<milliseconds>(system_clock::now()));
}
```

which just output for me:

```
09/15/17 13:17:40.466 UTC
```

Comment: I think it's better to have the examples here not `using namespace whatever`, so that it's clearer which functions and types come from which namespace.

Comment: One of the problems is that the namespaces are changing with time:  `floor` was in namespace `date`, but starting with C++17 is in namespace `std::chrono`.  By C++20, everything will be in `std::chrono`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Is there an easy way to discard trailing zeroes (and `.`, if necessary) in sub-second part of string produced by `date::format("%FT%TZ", p)` where `p` is a `system_clock::time_point`?

Comment: The best way to control the precision of the output is to truncate the precision of the input to `format`, such as the truncation to `milliseconds` in the example above.  There is no automatic way to detect trailing zeroes at run-time.  the only way to do so is to do custom post-processing on the generated string (reverse searching for zeroes).

Answer (score 24):

The most flexible way to do so is to convert it to `struct tm` and then use `strftime` (it's like `sprintf` for time). Something like:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::time_t now_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
std::tm now_tm = *std::localtime(&now_c);
/// now you can format the string as you like with `strftime`
```

Look up the documentation for `strftime` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime).

If you have `localtime_s` or `localtime_r` available you should use either in preference to `localtime`.

There are many other ways to do this, but, while mostly easier to use, these result in some predefined string representation. You could just "hide" all of the above in a function for ease of use.

Comment: Why is this preferable to using Mr. Hinnant's library?

Comment: Mr. Hinnant's library is not part of the C++ standard yet, while `strftime()` has been a part of C standard for a long time. It seems that in C++20 Mr. Hinnant's library will be a part of the C++ standard - when that happens, it will be hard to make a firm preference (it would depend on your needs and experience).

Comment: localtime is not thread safe!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but is this not precise only to the nearest second?

Comment: @EdwardFalk You are right, `struct tm` only has seconds, it does not include any smaller time unit measure.

Answer (score 24):

### Code solution

The following function converts from `chrono` `time_point` to string (serialization).

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

using time_point = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point;
std::string serializeTimePoint( const time_point& time, const std::string& format)
{
    std::time_t tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(time);
    std::tm tm = *std::gmtime(&tt); //GMT (UTC)
    //std::tm tm = *std::localtime(&tt); //Locale time-zone, usually UTC by default.
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::put_time( &tm, format.c_str() );
    return ss.str();
}

// example
int main()
{
    time_point input = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << serializeTimePoint(input, "UTC: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") << std::endl;

}
```

### Time zone

The `time_point` data-type has no internal representation for the time-zone, in consequence, the time-zone is aggregated by the conversion to `std::tm` (by the functions `gmtime` or `localtime`). It is not recommended to add/substract the time-zone from the input, because you would get an incorrect time-zone displayed with `%Z`, thus, it is better to set the correct local time (OS dependent) and use `localtime()`.

### Technical vs User-friendly serialization

For technical usage, hard-coded time format is a good solution. However, to display to users, one should use a `locale` to retrieve the user preference and show time-stamp in that format.

### C++20

Since C++20, we have nice serialization and parsing functions for time_point and duration.

- `std::chrono::to_stream`
- `std::chrono::format`

Comment: You create std::string from literal and then take c_str() from it => redundant malloc under hood. There is std::string_view for such purposes.

Comment: Correct, if you have access to C++17, you can optimize this code with `std::string_view`, otherwise, `const char*` is also a possibility.

Comment: I replaced time_point with auto

Answer (score 1):

A lot like Adrian's answer, but with (optional) milliseconds and GMT/localtime switch.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
static std::string timePointToString(const Clock::time_point &tp, const std::string &format, bool withMs = true, bool utc = true)
{
    const Clock::time_point::duration tt = tp.time_since_epoch();
    const time_t durS = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(tt).count();
    std::ostringstream ss;
    if (const std::tm *tm = (utc ? std::gmtime(&durS) : std::localtime(&durS))) {
        ss << std::put_time(tm, format.c_str());
        if (withMs) {
            const long long durMs = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(tt).count();
            ss << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << int(durMs - durS * 1000);
        }
    }
    // gmtime/localtime() returned null ?
    else {
        ss << "<FORMAT ERROR>";
    }
    return ss.str();
}

int main() {
    const auto tp = Clock::now();
    std::cout << timePointToString(tp, "%Z %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`> GMT 2022-04-30 13:44:09.720`

Test: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/43wsMbrMcmx

Granted it only appends the milliseconds and they're not part of the template... that would cost extra!

Answer (score 0):

It will become easier with C++20 (as mentioned in
Adrian Maire's answer.)

```
#include <chrono>
#include <format>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  auto t = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  std::string s = std::format("{0:%F %R %Z}", t);
  std::cout << s << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Note, As of now (February 2023) `std::format` is not implemented yet in most compiler releases, but hopefully will be soon in new releases. (You can check with preprocessor macros `__has_include(<format>)` and `__cpp_lib_format`.)

Docs on std::format: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format

The format syntax (`"%F %T %Z"`) is similar to `strftime()` or `std::put_time()` (haven't checked what the differences are, though) and documented at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/formatter.