# How do I use std::chrono to return the date and time as a string in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, datetime, time, c++14

I was looking at a similar post, that showed how to use the `ctime` header file, to return the time as a string, but since the release of C++11 there has been an addition that was `std::chrono`. But having this feature in `chrono`, how can I use it? Even our application uses the old `ctime`, header to return the date/time. This is the code, we're currently using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int returnTime()
{
    time_t rt;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char tbf[80];
    time(&rt);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rt);
    strftime(tbf, sizeof(tbf), "%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S", timeinfo);
string _now(tbf);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no such headers as `ctime.h` and `chrono.h`, there is `<ctime>` and `<chrono>`. That being said `<chrono>` doesn't have what you ask for.

Comment: @DeiDei The IDE we use, demands us to use '.h' for all headers.

Comment: stdax.h should be the first header (or even better not to use it and disable Recompiled headers)

Comment: @SayanN. That sounds like a bad ide. Also if that were the case how can you include `<iostream>`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34858704/8491726

Comment: Indeed a bad IDE! Now I'm updating the question with the one compiled using VS2017

Comment: I've added an answer to the original question which gives an alternative that is easier to use, more flexible, type-safe, and being proposed for standardization: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46240575/576911

Comment: All the code has been fixed

Comment: The C++ error was because of a new VS2017 update that broke several headers

Comment: Finally fixed - the code is fully functional now!