# Create std::chrono::time_point from string

Tags: c++, c++20

A [program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46240575/2394762) like this

```
int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now() << '\n';
}
```

prints something like `2017-09-15 13:11:34.356648`.

Assume I have a string literal `"2017-09-15 13:11:34.356648"` in my code.

What is the right way to create `std::chrono::time_point` from it in C++20?

Comment: FYI: [std::chrono::parse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/parse) (since C++20)

Comment: The (currently most voted answer) of the suggested duplicate refers to a pre-C++20 solution. Actually, it would be nice to add a C++20 answer here or there. What makes me uncertain: While `date::from_stream(str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` might work for the current sample, it will break for other locales. And, finally a stupid idea: If you used `operator<<()` for output... Did you try `operator>>()` for input?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat can it parse nanoseconds?

Comment: With a bit luck, Howard E. Hinnant may answer this. He's the author of that C++20 formatting stuff and usually reacts on questions concerning time related I/O. I must admit that I don't know but I would suspect that the formatted I/O is capable for all what can be internally represented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be clear, there is no `namespace date` in C++20.  So the code in the question should look like:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now() << '\n';
}
```

The inverse of this is `std::chrono::parse` which operates on streams.  You can also use `std::chrono::from_stream` if desired.  `parse` is a stream manipulator that makes the syntax a little nicer.

```
istringstream in{"2017-09-15 13:11:34.356648"};
system_clock::time_point tp;
in >> parse("%F %T", tp);
```

(I've dropped the namespaces just to keep the verbosity down)

The `locale` used is the global locale in effect at the time the `istringstream` is constructed.  If you prefer another `locale` use the `imbue` member function to set the desired `locale`.  The `locale` will only impact the decimal point character in this example.

The `%T` will read up to whatever precision the input `time_point` has (which varies with platform from microseconds to nanoseconds).  If you want to be sure you can parse nanoseconds even if `system_clock::time_point` is coarser than that, then you can parse into a `sys_time<nanoseconds>` which is a type alias for `time_point<system_clock, nanoseconds>`.

```
sys_time<nanoseconds> tp;
in >> parse("%F %T", tp);
```

If the input stream has precision less than the input `time_point`, there is no problem.  What the stream has will be read, and no more.  If the input stream has precision finer than the input `time_point`, then the parse stops at the precision of the `time_point`, and the remaining digits are left unparsed in the stream.

[Other `strptime`-like parsing flags are supported.](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.parse#tab:time.parse.spec)