# Add offset to a time

Tags: c++

I have a string that I convert to time based on certain format

```
 const std::string format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S";
    std::istringstream dateStream(date);

    std::tm tm = {}; 
    dateStream >> std::get_time(&tm, format.c_str());
```

Then I want to add an offset to it
and print the result as a string:

```
 tm.tm_min += offset;
    std::mktime(&tm);

    std::ostringstream resultStream;
    resultStream << std::put_time(&tm, format.c_str());
```

It seems to work here https://godbolt.org/z/q7svh51Y7

But when I run it on my local system I receive 2023-09-26T18:18:23 instead of 2023-09-26T17:18:23
Could you help with a solution for this ?

Comment: Daylight savings? What is the value of `tm.tm_isdst` (before and after the call to `std::mktime`)? Perhaps it could also be time-zone dependent?

Comment: You want to add 330 to tm_min. But doesn't tm_min need to be in range [0,59]? What is this offset? Is this offset in minutes or seconds?

Comment: First I would try with `offset=0` then check `tm.tm_isdst` as mention in first comment.

Comment: @kiner_shah this is not a problem, function `std::mktime` normalizes this data structure. That is why most probably this one hour difference was hidden into a `tm.tm_isdst`.

Comment: before: tm.tm_isdst: 0
after: tm.tm_isdst: 1

Comment: @MarekR, good to know that. Thanks :-)

Comment: I can read one line in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime): *"If the std::tm object was obtained from std::get_time or the POSIX strptime, the value of tm_isdst is indeterminate, and needs to be set explicitly before calling mktime."*

Comment: The easiest way to fix this is to add extra `std::mktime(&tm);` just before reading from string into `tm` to enforce initialization of `tm.tm_isdst`.

Comment: If you have c++20 available try using chrono parsing instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71183145/create-stdchronotime-point-from-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the C API (`mktime`, `strftime`, `strptime`, etc.) conflates "broken down time" with "local time", and applies the UTC offset in fun and unexpected ways.

There are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Continue using the C API but add:

   ```
   std::tm tm = {}; 
   tm.tm_isdst = -1;  // Add this line
   ```

This works.  But this API is so hard to use that this type of bug is pretty much guaranteed to hit you again.

2. Use chrono and C++20.  However if you are stuck with C++17 there's a [free, open-source, header-only C++20 chrono preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) that works with C++11/14/17, is much safer and easier to use, and will easily port to C++20 when the time comes.

   ```
   #include "date/date.h"
   #include <chrono>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <sstream>

   std::string
   setOffsetForTime(const std::string& date, const std::chrono::seconds offset)
   {
       const std::string format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S";
       std::istringstream dateStream(date);

       date::sys_seconds tm = {}; 
       dateStream >> date::parse(format, tm);  

       tm += offset;

       std::ostringstream resultStream;
       resultStream << date::format(format, tm);
       return resultStream.str();
   }

   int main() {
       std::string dateString1 = "2023-09-26T11:48:23";
       const std::chrono::minutes offset{330};
       std::cout<< setOffsetForTime(dateString1, offset);

       return 0;
   }
   ```

As you can see the structure of the new code is not unlike what you already have.  But here are the important differences:

A. It uses type-safe units for time such as `minutes` and `seconds` instead of `int`.

B. The type `sys_seconds` has the semantics of a time point in UTC.  No time zones are involved.  If you want a conversion to local time that is something that happens explicitly in your code, not implicitly.

To port this to C++20 you will drop `#include "date/date.h"` and change several `date::` to `std::chrono::`.  And the `format` string will need to be slightly altered for the formatting statement:  `"{:%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S}"`.

[Demo of ported C++20 code.](https://godbolt.org/z/cGG8G3vov)

Comment: thanks a lot, but I don't want to use other open source library for c++17, do you see any other solution that can work with only c++17 other than tm.tm_isdst = -1;?

Comment: Yes, you could write your own date/time library.  Here are public domain algorithms to get you started: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html